# How to Click on ActiveX controls in Word Using AutoIT?

Tags: vba, ms-word, sandbox, autoit

I am trying to automate the clicking of activeX controls in word using AutoIT.

**Method 1**:

1. Get all InlineShapes on the page
2. See if their type is ActiveX control ( type == 5)
3. get their locations relative to the word page using a conversion to the Shape Type.

The shape type gives you left/top location wrt the word page itself, and the inline shape type gives you width and height.

In theory, at this point I have enough to find the vertices of the control on the page as:

```
    vertices: top left = (left, top)
              top right =  (left + width, top)
              bottom left = (left, top + height)
              bottom right = (left + width, top + height)
```

4. Once you get the vertices, move the mouse to the center of the control by averaging its corners, and use MouseClick(xpos, ypos).

However, this is still only relative to the page.

I don't know how to find the borders of the page itself, so I'm not sure how to do this other than just traverse from the top(?).

**Method 2** I'm considering:

Is there some selection type that lets me select the activeX control from InlineShapes/Shapes and lets me click or run some action on the selected object? This would be much simpler than method 1 and I'd love to hopefully find something in this regard.

What are the ways for me to complete this section?

Comment: By "borders of the page" do you mean the margins? `Range.Sections(1).PageSetup` gets you the margin settings properties. Also page width and height.

Comment: In Word-speak, a border is a line you see. A margin is the distance between the edge of the paper and where the block of text is/could be.